# Spring Batch : Partition file based on custom logic and write to DB in parallel

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am working on this usecase to process a large file in spring batch wherein I have to bucketize lines in a file into multiple buckets (db shards) and write them to the DB (write to each shard in parallel ). Which shard each line goes to is dependent on the shardkey, which is part of the input file, on each line. I have thought of 2 options to do this :

Option 1:

```
Split the original file into n diffent files using Classifiers in Spring batch. 
Process each file using split and flows and write them to the DB.
```

Option 2:

```
Read each line and reorder the file such that all buckets are in order. While doing this I keep track of where each bucket starts and ends. 
Create a partioner and provide the above info in its ExcutionContext and write to the DB in parallel.
```

Is there anything better I can do to ? Any clue which of the above options is better ?

Thanks

Comment: If you can write in parallel, why do you need to classify the records when splitting them?  Why can't you just split the file and write the records in parallel?

Comment: I use the classifier to do the splitting. I will have to look at the shardkey to figure out which bucket it goes to Is there a better way of doing this other than using a classifier ? I have implemented it similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453254/routing-data-to-multiple-files-in-item-writer-based-on-items-property-as-criter . I have 12 different splits, so not too happy with the way my xml looks.

Comment: I'm just wondering why do the sharding during the split and not during the write?  Just use a simple utility to split the file by number of lines then determine the bucket as you write the records to the db

Comment: To maximize my write throughput, I need all the records in each shard at the time of writing. I know I can write at the rate of x per second, so need the entire x while writing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the chunk processing (Reading + Processing + Writing) to split the file you have. You could create a custom tasklet to encapsulate the logic of splitting the file in new temporally ones on a "staging area" based on the shardkeys obtained in the lines you're reading. This splitting operation is cheap to do in java code but depending on your environment you could even call an [system command](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/patterns.html#executingSystemCommands) to do sorting and splitting.

Once the splitting is done you could use the MultiResourcePartitioner as described in [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/partitionFileJob.xml) sample to do the parallel processing. Also consider developing an step/tasklet to clean all temp files from the staging directory before processing if your large file is an third-party monthly/weekly incremental file.

Comment: Well, I did think about that, but system commands mean I am restricting my batch to work only on UNIX envs. We use Windows too, so that becomes a problem.