# processing grouped records and outputting them into multiple files with spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a database table with employees in it that can be grouped by department in the form of:
[employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhbFB.png)

department_id|employee_id| employee_firstname|employee_lastname
    1         |1          | john              | d
    1         |2          | mary              | s
    2         |3          | ray               | b
    3         |4          | joe               | d

I would like to group it by department and process it into separate output files (ideally excel but for simplicity it can be csv). Each department output file will contain its employees so department1.csv will have first 2 records, department2.csv will have third record and department3.csv will have forth record.
Do you know how to achieve it with spring batch? 
Thanks in advance,
Grama

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that table is going to be big, so the data will be read in chunks, processed and stored into multiple files

Comment: this might give you some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453254/routing-data-to-multiple-files-in-item-writer-based-on-items-property-as-criter

Comment: Thanks Shankar, I have seen this example, the idea with the classifier works for predefined writers when you know exactly a set of codes you can define a number of writers for each code. As one of the users mentioned there: 
 
"I can not use your solution because your solution inherently assumes that the number of writers are this many. But in my problem, I do not know the number and type of writers before hand and so I can not define abcItemWriter/xyzItemWriter before hand" – Vicky
 My case is the same, I dont know exactly how many departments I will have. Any other ideas?