# Invoke particular writer based on operation type?

Tags: java, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am working one batch which reads each row and insert into db as well as write in file. I want to write this below data in database as well as in file. So needs to call particular writer using `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`. I have file which has following rows:

`DATA,I,1,John,Shiazo,Sushi`

`DATA,U,8,Pablo,Carmen`

`DATA,D,9,Diego,Sergio`

`DATA,I,10,rucha,rekha`

Here, I stands for insert, U stands for update and D stands for delete. How should I call one particular writer for insert, other is for update and one more is for delete. This three writer will work differently based on operations(Insert, Update and Delete) and there is one more writer which will always for work for writing data in file.

Below is my sample code:

```
@Classifier
public List<String> classify(Object object) {
    String type = "Success";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(person.getOperationType().contentEquals("I")){
        String insert = "I";
        list.add(type);
        list.add(insert);   
    }else if(person.getOperationType().contentEquals("U")){
        String update = "U";
        list.add(type);
        list.add(insert);
    }else{
        delete = "D";
        list.add(type);
        list.add(delete);
    }
}
```

Sample xml writer code:

```
<bean id="classifierFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter" scope="step">       <property name="classifier">           <bean class="org.springframework.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">             <property name="routerDelegate">
                <bean class="com.iz.batchprocessing.writer.SuccessFailClassifier" scope="step"/>
            </property>
            <property name="matcherMap">
                <map>
                     <entry key="I" value-ref="jdbcInsertItemWriter" /> //insert writer, here I want access ArrayList
                     <entry key="U" value-ref="jdbcUpdateItemWriter" /> //update writer, here I want access ArrayList
                     <entry key="D" value-ref="jdbcDeleteItemWriter" /> //delete writer, here I want access ArrayList
                     <entry key="Success" value-ref="successMultiFileItemWriter" /> //common file writer
                </map>
            </property>
             </bean>     
        </property> </bean>
```

Please tell me how can I do this? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Where are you preparing this list? in processor? Why do you need three separate writers, three different methods in a single writer not work?

Comment: is your question, simply to ask , How to use `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`?

Comment: No, my question is not how to use `ClassifierCompositeItemWriter`. I am preparing this list in writer classifier. As I am using xml configuration of spring batch, as per I know much about spring batch, I cannot make any three different methods in spring batch. If you know, please post a sample code.
I want to send multiple parameters from classifier such as "Success and I" or "Success and D" or "Success and U". At this point only, I am stuck up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not worked on this type of writer but by looking at [another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453254/routing-data-to-multiple-files-in-item-writer-based-on-items-property-as-criter) and answer by - Serkan Arıkuşu , I see that you need to return a value / key from your `Classifier` and that will be used by `matcherMap` to map appropriate writers.

I see that you are not returning any **key** from your classifier, you are simply making assignment to those String variables but not returning anything.

By looking at that answer, I can say that you need to embed that key in your `Item` being written and return that key for each item from your `Classifier`.

Answer by Mukesh Sabde there is a complete code sample.

Instead of adding Strings to List and returning List , you should return concatenated String and those should be the keys in matcher map.

I looked at code of `BackToBackPatternClassifier` class , it has two private fields - `private Classifier<C, String> router;` &

```
private Classifier<String, T> matcher;
```

So you can't specify a `List` as key for `matcherMap` property. It has to be a String and you were wrong there.

For your case, `C` is Spring Batch `Item` to be written and `T` is `ItemWriter`.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thank you for answering to my question. To some extend, your answer is helping me. 
And I want to add one thing that I am returning the list which I forgot to post in code. Sorry for making you trouble.

Comment: I think, you are not required to return list but only `person.getOperationType()` from classifier. Also, I guess , list returned by processor to writer will automatically be filtered , you are not supposed to do that filtering.

Comment: Ok, I changed my code now. I am only returning string as you said `person.getOperationType()`. Now, I have compositeWriter in which I have two writer, one is `fileWriter` which will always write in file and another writer is `DatabaseClassifierItemWriter` , in that I am mapping entry key with reference value as `jdbcInsertItemWriter`, `jdbcUpdateItemWriter` and `jdbcDeleteItemWriter`. But now neither my file is getting generated nor inserting into db. And also, there are no errors.

Comment: I mean those were generic guidelines and the way you wrote code was wrong. You have to debug your application step by step.In absence of explicit errors, you need to debug harder.

Comment: Ok sir sure. Thank you so much for your kind help.

Comment: I have updated my answer after looking at code of `BackToBackPatternClassifier`. Please let me know for any confusion.